# jQuery MultiSelect dropdownlist how to access results?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How can I get the results from a JQUery Multi-select dropdownlist as called per an mvc3/razor?

http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/04/jquery-multiselect/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The multiselect plugin uses the `[]` notation to send the selected values to the server. As always we start by writing a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<string> SelectedValues { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return new[]
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "item 1" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "item 2" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "item 3" },
            };
        }
    }
}
```

then a controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

a corresponding view:

```
@model MyViewModel

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.multiSelect.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#SelectedValues").multiSelect();
    });
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.SelectedValues, Model.Items)
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

and finally a model binder associated with the `IEnumerable<string>` type and which will work with the `[]` notation used by the plugin:

```
public class MultiSelectModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var model = (MyViewModel)base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName + "[]");
        if (value != null)
        {
            return value.RawValue;
        }
        return model;
    }
}
```

The last part is to register the model binder in `Application_Start`:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(IEnumerable<string>), new MultiSelectModelBinder());
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this to get selected values

```
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model, FormCollection collection)
    {
        string selectedValues=collection["SelectedValues[]"]; //here you get comma separated values
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: This was an awesome little shortcut instead of iterator through the [] model.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can also recieve the selected values by adding a parameter to your action.

For instance, lets say you have following listbox:

```
//Controller GET
public ActionResult ManageUsers()
{
    ViewBag.Users = new SelectList(repository.GetAllUsers(), "Id", "Email");
    return View();
}

//View
@Html.ListBox(ViewBag.Users as SelectList, new { @id = "users" })

//Controller POST
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ManageUsers(List<int> users)
{
    //Manage all the selected users which will appear in the List.

    return View()...
}
```

I believe you can have an array as type instead of a generic list aswell, havn't tried it myself though, the key however is to name the parameter the same as the html element id for the listbox.