# How to preselect values in jquery multiselect?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm using the following jquery multi-select control ( http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/04/jquery-multiselect/#configuring ) and need to pre-select some values in the dropdown list.

Can I do this with by passing in a comma delimited items list ("valID1,valID2") somehow (any other methods)?  I already have a stored list of what was previously selected.

Answer (score 1):

Follow [my suggestion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816246/jquery-multiselect-dropdownlist-how-to-access-results/7817388#7817388) and then slightly re-adapt the controller action, like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        // preselect the first and the third item but obviously
        // this could be any list of ids
        SelectedValues = new[] { "1", "3" };
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Would something like this work in the controller?             foreach (SelectListItem sl in TitleList)
            {
                if (NetworkList.Exists(x => x == sl.Value)) { sl.Selected = true; }
            }

Comment: @Jacquo, I have no idea how your comment has any relation to the matter here. I don't understand it. In ASP.NET MVC in order to preselect a bunch of items in a multiselect dropdownlist you simply assign the corresponding view mjodel property to a given list of values.

Comment: Your model works!  I was just curious if you could build a select list in the controller and select what select list items will be selected in the view.