# Mvc3 and Jquery Multiselect, sending values to server not working?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, multi-select

I am trying to use Jquery Multiselect plugin from [Beautiful site](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/04/jquery-multiselect/) and MVC3 together to send values to server. As shown in [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816246/jquery-multiselect-dropdownlist-how-to-access-results) from Darin the key is to create `MultiSelectModelBinder` class that will, I guess, recognize values send from client, because the multiselect plugin uses the [] notation to send the selected values to the server. My aproach is a little diferent, i fill *dropDownList* from my controller and not the model, keeping the model clean, and also been able to fill the list from Database. I used Darins example to create `MultiSelectModelBinder` and register it,in the model binder in `Application_Start()`. My problem is that I always keep getting empty Model back to my controller, here is the code:

**MODEL:**

```
public class PersonsSearchModel
{
    public string Person { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }

    //here is my Cities collection
    public IEnumerable<string> Cities { get; set; }
}
```

**VIEW:**

```
@model MyNamespace.Model.PersonsSearchModel
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "Persons", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "GET",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "results",
    LoadingElementId = "progress"
},
    new { @id = "searchFormPerson" }
))
{    
  <span>
      @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.Person, new { @class = "halfWidth"})
  </span> 
  <span>
      @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.Company, new { @class = "halfWidth"})
  </span> 
  <span>
      @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.Cities, Model.Items, new { @id="combobox1"})
  </span>
  <input name="Search" type="submit" class="searchSubmit" value="submit" />
}
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

    var listCities = new List<SelectListItem>();
    listCities.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Select one...", Value = "" });
    listCities.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "New York", Value = "New York" });
    listCities.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Boston", Value = "Boston" });
    listCities.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Miami", Value = "Miami" });
    listCities.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "London", Value = "London" });

    ViewBag.Cities = listCities;

    return View();

}

public class MultiSelectModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var model = (PersonsSearchModel)base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName + "[]");
        if (value != null)
        {
            return value.RawValue;
        }
        return model;

    }
}
```

Here the data from client sholud arive, butt is always null?

```
public PartialViewResult Search(PersonsSearchModel psm)
{
     var person = psm.Person;
     var company = psm.Company;
     var city =  psm.Cities.ElementAt(0);

     return GetResultPartialView(city);

}
```

**GLOBAL.asax.cs**

```
 protected void Application_Start()
 {
     //...
    //model binder

     ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(IEnumerable<string>), new
     FinessenceWeb.Controllers.PersonsController.MultiSelectModelBinder());
 }
```

**JQUERY**

```
$("#combobox1").multiSelect();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... After looking into DOM, and Jquery plugin, turns out the plugin gives the select element, atribute name, current id, so they are the same, and the form, well.. look's at the name attr. So solution wolud be:

```
$("#Cities").multiSelect();
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, although your provided solution still works. There is another way of doing it with less effort.

Actually defaultModelbinder does bind to multiple selected values if you can change your input parameter to `List<inputparameter>` and change the line `@Html.DropDownListFor` to `@Html.ListBoxFor.`

The key difference between these 2 controls is, First one being a single selection box  and second one being a multiple selector.

Hope this helps some one having the same issue.